# page not redirecting in javascript after clicking a button which is inside a form

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <button onclick="demo()" name="btn">click here</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function demo()
        {
            location.href="http://www.google.com";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

if the button is placed without the form tag it is working properly. If it is placed inside the  tags its not getting redirected when clicked on it.

Comment: do you have an error in the console ? Something like "X-cross posting" ?

Comment: The default action of a button in a form is to submit the form. A pending submission blocks all changes to the page's location. If you don't need the form, just omit it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <button onclick="return demo()" name="btn">click here</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function demo()
        {
            location.href="http://www.google.com";
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This modification prevent the default action of clicking on a button inside a form (which is submitting it) and relocate to google.

If you don't need the form do not use it.

Comment: Are you sure that returning `false` from `onclick` would prevent the form to be submitted. I know this would work with `onsubmit`event.

Comment: Yes return false is the javascript equivalent of e.preventDefault() in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Always specify the type attribute for a `<button>` element. Different browsers use different default types for the `<button>` element.

If you use the `<button>` element in an HTML form, different browsers may submit different values. Use `<input>` to create buttons in an HTML form.

```
<form>
  <button type="button" onclick="demo()" name="btn">Click Here</button>
  <!-- or you can use input element -->
  <input type="button" onclick="demo()" value="Click Here" />
</form>

<script>
function demo() {
  window.location.href = "http://www.google.com"
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be look like this.

```
<form>
    <button onclick="demo(event)" name="btn">click here</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function demo(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

or you can try this also

```
<form>
    <button onclick="demo(event)" name="btn">click here</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function demo(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Why should it look like this?

Comment: when you use button tag it is submitting a form. but before submitting you need to fire your event.

Comment: Yes, but the browser takes care of the firing order, and the click event in this case is always executed before submission. Please add some explanation to your answer (it works) so, that OP can understand what have you changed and why. Not my down vote, though.